# Equivalence Relation question

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

"Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and let $f : A \to B$ be a function. Define a relation on $B$ as follows. If $a, b \in B$, we say that $a\mathrel{R}b$ if and only if there exists some $c \in A$ such that $f(c) = a$ and $f(c) = b$. Prove that $R$ need not be an equivalence relation."

I'm having trouble understanding why this is not necessarily an equivalence relation. Based off the discussion in class about this problem, the professor stated that is not an equivalence relation because it fails to achieve the reflexivity criteria, but I do not see why.

If my memory serves me correctly, the counterexample given was,

> Let $A = \{ 1 \}$ and $B = \{ 1,2 \}$ and $f(1) = 1$. Then $(2,2) \notin R$, so it is not reflexive and not an equivalence relation.

But this seems like it is not an equivalence relation simply because of the way we defined our sets and relation.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the professor didn't state this is *never* an equivalence relation. He stated that *it may happen* that this is not an equivalence relation, and gave an example in which this happens. So what do you not understand?

Comment: It depends on the function: if $f$ is surjective, then it is an equivalence relation. In the specific example given $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: $aRb$ iff $a=b$ and $a,b$ are in the image of $f$.

Comment: $f$ might not be a surjection. If it *is* onto $B$, then $R$ is in fact the identity relation on $B$. Notice that the definition is basically: $a \in \operatorname{range}(f)$ and $a = b$

Comment: @Adayah Yes you are understanding correctly but it confuses me because the other previous problem given on the homework was (2):  Let A and B be sets and let f : A → B be a function. Define a relation on A as follows. If a, b ∈ A, we say that aRb if and only if there exists some c ∈ B such that f(a) = c and f(b) = c. Prove that R is an equivalence relation on A. Could I not just use the same logic given here by defining some function that does not satisfy reflexivity, therefore disproving that Question #2 is not an equivalence relation either?

Comment: @feonyte: To answer the question in your last comment. The difference between the two exercises is in the definition of functions. For a function $f:A\to B$, **every** element of $A$ has to be an input, but it's not necessarily true that **every** element of $B$ is an output. Which also explains why the relation in Question #1 (from your original post) is reflexive iff $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal R$ is not necessarily an equivalence relation ON $B$ because $f:A\to B$ is not necessarily a surjection. For example, let $A=B=\Bbb R$ and consider the "zero function" $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=0$. Clearly, $(1,1)\notin\mathcal R$ because there is no $c\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(c)=1$. Therefore, in this example, $\mathcal R$ is not an equivalence relation on $B$.